# cannot reference resources after change of package name

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I wanted to publish an app, so I changed the package name (from com to -> QRcodeAndBarcodeApp), and now I cannot import resources
"MainActivity.kt: (48, 12): Unresolved reference: example"

```kotlin
import com.example.qrcodeapp.R
```

it works as an app but I'm unable to create Signed Apk (the error I listed above occurs during creating one)

I did some changes in androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="QRcodeAndBarcodeApp.example.qrcodeapp">
```

and in build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "QRCodeAndBarcodeApp.example.qrcodeapp"
```

but that changed nothing...

Comment: There’s a package name set in your gradle file to be used in your manifest and that your app will be known by, but also the package that some or all of your classes might be in. The former affects the package your resource IDs will be in, and if the latter doesn’t match you’ll have to update all your import statements so they refer to the new resources package.

Comment: You need to change your import statements to match the new package.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to change all your imports to match the new package name.

#### Example

Change

```
import com.example.qrcodeapp.R
```

To

```
import QRcodeAndBarcodeApp.example.qrcodeapp.R
```